# Is NSSortDescriptor thread safe?

Tags: objective-c, thread-safety

I have a setter for a class that I was wanting to have input sorted on setting (it's called infrequently enough the cost is OK), and I was thinking to help make it a little faster I'd create a static NSSortDescriptor to use since the sorting parameters are always the same.

The setter is meant to be atomic though, and I was wondering if it's safe to use the same instance of NSSortDescriptor across multiple threads outside of an @synchronized block (since I was going to sort the incoming array before I entered the @synchronzied block).  Is the following code thread safe?  Or is this too much premature optimization?

```
- (void) setMyArray:(NSArray*)newMyArray
{
    static NSArray *sorter = nil;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
      if ( sorter == nil )
      {
        NSSortDescriptor *sortObj = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"size" ascending:YES];
        sorter = [[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortObj] retain];
      }
    }

    NSArray *sorted = [myNewArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorter];

    @synchronized(self) 
    {
       // set iVar from sorted array...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation specifically](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html) states:

> Immutable objects are generally
>   thread-safe; once you create them, you
>   can safely pass these objects to and
>   from threads. Of course, when using
>   immutable objects, you still need to
>   remember to use reference counts
>   correctly. If you inappropriately
>   release an object you did not retain,
>   you could cause an exception later.

Since, as hoha observed, NSSortDescriptor is immutable, it is thread safe *unless specifically noted otherwise* (typically in the class documentation).

Comment: I know that immutable objects are thread safe, but as you noted in a response below it's bad to assume something is immutable just because it looks immutable... and the docs don't say it is immutable.  I'll also file a bug on the docs in this case so that it's clearer going forward.

Comment: Filed Radar, bug ID  9131037 .

Answer (score 0):

`NSSortDescriptor` doesn't have any visible ways to change it and it doesn't have any reasons to change its state internally so it is most probably thread-safe (unless Apple do hacks on it in framework code which I doubt).

As for optimization it is (almost) always premature without actual profiling. In this case though I'll do the same thing with static var - mostly to have a place where my sort strategy is clearly declared/defined.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to blindly assume things are thread-safe when they have no documentation to that effect. You have no way of knowing whether it manipulates caches internally or does any other form of modification.

Comment: Never *ever* assume that anything is thread safe.  If something is thread safe, **it will be explicitly documented as such**.  Making any kind of assumptions like this *will lead to crashes* (and often will lead to crashes after a software update).

Comment: @Kevin Ballard: Yes, I have not. I can't imagine any mutable state in sort descriptor but I can't prove its non-existence either. That's why I said - "most probably". BTW "Threading Programming Guide" states that "immutable objects are generally thread-safe" which served as indirect evidence for me.

Comment: @bbum: "it will be explicitly documented as such". Does that mean that there is only one thread safe class in Cocoa (`NSUserDefaults`)? http://www.google.com/search?q=thread+safe+site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fmac%2F%23documentation%2FCocoa

Comment: Sorry, with `NSOperationQueue` there are two of them.

Comment: Huh?  The documentation I linked to has a list of thread safe classes and a list of non-thread safe classes *and* the discussion I quoted before.  How much more explicit do you need?!

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that list, my fault. Still there is no `NSSortDescriptor` in it. And "Immutable objects are generally thread-safe" != "immutable objects are explicitly documented as thread safe". So while we agree on thread safety of `NSSortDescriptor` it is still an assumption, nothing more. Documentation is just not clear enough on this. Maybe they discussed such things at some WWDC, I don't know.

Comment: Bug filed, btw.  I agree that the documentation is too wishy washy in this area and have asked for it to be enhanced.